# /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hola estoy intentando crear una app con Ruby on Rails pero cuando creo un proyecto me da el siguiente error:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler (LoadError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/generators/app_base.rb:328:in `bundle_command'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/generators/app_base.rb:344:in `run_bundle'
from (eval):1:in `run_bundle'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `block in invoke_all'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `each'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `map'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `invoke_all'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/thor/group.rb:232:in `dispatch'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/commands/application.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/cli.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
```

No consigo saber que es lo que no funciona, ya que he seguido todos los pasos de instalación como me marcan

Comment: ¿Qué pasos seguiste para instalar rails y crear tu app?

Comment: https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/16.04 los que explican en esta pagina

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que se ve en el log que has añadido, el problema es que te falta una gema muy importante llamada [`bundler`](https://bundler.io/), la cual, permite gestionar versiones y dependencias de otras gemas.

Se puede instalar como cualquier otra gema:

```
gem install bundler
```

Seguramente necesites permisos de superusuario (instalarla como `root` o añadiendo `sudo` al comando anterior) porque estás utilizando la versión de Ruby que viene por defecto en Ubuntu 16.04.

Como comentario adicional, si quieres trabajar con otra versión de Ruby, o simplemente no depender de la versión de Ruby del sistema, te aconsejo que hagas uso de [`rvm`](https://rvm.io/) o [`rbenv`](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv).

Saludos.